# Android: MPEG4Writer fails to start when using OMXCodec as MediaSource

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, stagefright, openmax

I'm trying to encode a video from a byte array buffer and to do so I'm using `MPEG4Writer` API from native code.

I have created my custom `MediaSource` class to provide the data and I'm wrapping it with `OMXCodec` to give it to `MPEG4Writer`:

```
sp<MediaSource> mVideoEncoder = OMXCodec::Create(client.interface(), omxEncMeta, true, mVideoOutSource);
mVideoEncoder->start();
```

`mVideoOutSource` is my custom `MediaSource` class, `omxEncMeta` is the following:

```
int32_t colorFormat = OMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;
int32_t width = 480;
int32_t height = 360;
int32_t frameRate = 24;
int32_t bitRate = 500 * 1024;
int32_t iFrameInterval = 1;

sp<MetaData> omxEncMeta = new MetaData;
omxEncMeta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyColorFormat, colorFormat);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyWidth, width);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyHeight, height);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyStride, width);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeySliceHeight, height);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyFrameRate, frameRate);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeySampleRate, frameRate);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyBitRate, bitRate);
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyIFramesInterval, iFrameInterval);
```

but when I call `start()` method it returns the error code `UNKNOWN_ERROR`.

Instead, if I try to give to `MPEG4Writer` directly my custom `MediaSource` (without wrapping it with `OMXCodec` it starts successfully but eventually it will stop recording with the error `Missing codec specific data` (after about 12 frames), and I think this is because my custom `MediaSource` provides only informations about the actual frames but nothing about the codec format.

I'm sure I'm missing something with `OMXCodec`, but I can't figure out what... Is there anyone who could provide me with a working example of a custom `MediaSource` for encoding? Or give me some hints on why this is not working at all?
If you need more informations just ask, thanks!

**EDIT**: I'm developing this against API 14 so please don't suggest me to use `MediaCodec` from API 16 :)

**EDIT**: This is how I'm starting `MPEG4Writer`:

```
int32_t outputFormat = OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4;
int64_t startTimeUs = systemTime() / 1000;
int32_t totalBitRate = bitRate;

sp<MetaData> meta = new MetaData;
meta->setInt64(kKeyTime, startTimeUs);
meta->setInt32(kKeyFileType, outputFormat);
meta->setInt32(kKeyBitRate, totalBitRate);

sp<MPEG4Writer> mWriter = new MPEG4Writer("/sdcard/encode_manual.mp4");
mWriter->addSource(mVideoEncoder);
status_t error = mWriter->start(meta.get());
if (error != OK) {
    LOGE("Writer NOT started! %x", error);
} else {
    LOGI("Writer started!");
}
```

---

This is the output of logcat (`adb logcat OMXClient:V OMXCodec:V *:W`):

```
W/ResourceType(  370): Skipping entry 0x7f04002f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
E/        ( 4127): Can't open file for reading
E/        ( 4127): Can't open file for reading
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  omx_video(): Inside Constructor()
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  omx_venc(): Inside component_init()
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): bool venc_dev::venc_validate_profile_level(OMX_U32*, OMX_U32*): Returning with eProfile = 1Level = 4
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  bool venc_dev::venc_open(OMX_U32)(): Init Profile/Level setting success
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): vidc.venc.debug.sliceinfo value is 0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  Component_init return value = 0x0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): WARNING: Requested i/p bufsize[40960],Driver's updated i/p bufsize = 262144
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): bool venc_dev::venc_validate_profile_level(OMX_U32*, OMX_U32*): Returning with eProfile = 1Level = 256
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  bool venc_dev::venc_set_param(void*, OMX_INDEXTYPE)(): Profile/Level setting success
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): bool venc_dev::venc_validate_profile_level(OMX_U32*, OMX_U32*): Returning with eProfile = 1Level = 64
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): Calling set level (Framerate) with 15
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): bool venc_dev::venc_validate_profile_level(OMX_U32*, OMX_U32*): Returning with eProfile = 1Level = 64
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): Calling set level (Bitrate) with 15
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): get_parameter: OMX_IndexParamVideoProfileLevelQuerySupported for Input port returned Profile:1, Level:2048
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): Profile/Level set equal to 1/64
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): bool venc_dev::venc_validate_profile_level(OMX_U32*, OMX_U32*): Returning with eProfile = 1Level = 64
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  venc_set_intra_period: nPFrames = 25 nBFrames = 0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): bool venc_dev::venc_validate_profile_level(OMX_U32*, OMX_U32*): Returning with eProfile = 1Level = 64
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): Calling set level (Bitrate) with 15
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_input_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_input_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_input_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_output_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  actual cnt = 5
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_output_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  actual cnt = 5
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_output_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  actual cnt = 5
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_output_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  actual cnt = 5
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  allocate_output_buffer()::
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  actual cnt = 5
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  unsigned int venc_dev::venc_start()(): Check Profile/Level set in driver before start
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  unsigned int venc_dev::venc_start()(): Driver Profile[3]/Level[15] successfully SET
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): ENC_CONFIG: Codec: 2, Profile 3, level : 15
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  ENC_CONFIG: Width: 480, Height:360, Fps: 25
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): ENC_CONFIG: Bitrate: 512000, RC: 3, I-Period: 25
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): ENC_CONFIG: qpI: 0, qpP: 80, qpb: 0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): ENC_CONFIG: VOP_Resolution: 4343391, Slice-Mode: 1, Slize_Size: 0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): ENC_CONFIG: EntropyMode: 1, CabacModel: 0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): ENC_CONFIG: DB-Mode: 2, alpha: 0, Beta: 0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): ENC_CONFIG: IntraMB/Frame: 18, HEC: 843271745
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155): Width 480, Height 360, w_round 480, h_round 368, yuv_size 294912 alignment 8192 count 2
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  Allocated virt:0x4432e000, FD: 145 of size 294912
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  Allocated virt:0x4432e000, FD: 145 of size 294912 at index: 0
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  Allocated virt:0x44895000, FD: 147 of size 294912
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):
E/OMX-VENC-720p(  155):  Allocated virt:0x44895000, FD: 147 of size 294912 at index: 1
E/TestEnc-JNI( 4127): Writer NOT started! 80000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out my (*dumb*) issue: I was calling `start()` on `mVideoEncoder` (the `OMXCodec` instance) before calling `start()` on `MPEG4Writer`, and this was giving the `UNKNOWN_ERROR`.

I solved by calling `start()` only on `MPEG4Writer` instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error that I think is important:

```
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeyBitRate, frameRate); // should set bitrate, 24 is too small
```

also

```
omxEncMeta->setInt32(kKeySampleRate, frameRate); // i don't think is of any use
```

Then: make sure your source returns this

```
virtual sp<MetaData> getFormat() {
    sp<MetaData> meta = new MetaData;
    meta->setInt32(kKeyWidth, mWidth);
    meta->setInt32(kKeyHeight, mHeight);
    meta->setInt32(kKeyColorFormat, mColorFormat);
    meta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_RAW);
    return meta;
}
```

The MediaBuffer you return from source should be the right size: 480*360*4(i think that is the case).

You should provide the adb logcat output: adb.exe logcat OMXClient:V OMXCodec:V *:W

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you were right about `kKeyBitRate` (I think I've copy-pasted it wrong :/) but also by fixing that and ensuring that my custom source is returning the same `MetaData` you suggested `MPEG4Writer` can't start... I've updated my question with the logcat output.

Comment: Also about `MediaBuffer` size: for `YUV420SemiPlanar` I think it should be `(width * height * 3) / 2`, anyway I tried also with `width * height * 4` but nothing changed...

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured out it was a very stupid error... Anyway thanks for your help, it was very useful! :)