# Difference between MediaCodec and OMXCodec

Tags: android, stagefright

I have just started to work on the Android Multimedia Framework (`Stagefright`) and have a basic idea of how local playback works in `AwesomePlayer` which uses `OMXCodec`.

I have been mapping my understanding using the `MediaPlayer` state diagram
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html and so far it has been pretty good. I have been able to map my understanding to the code.

But I look at the `ACodec` module (probably for streaming `rtsp`, `HLS` etc) I am finding difficulty.
I am not able to understand how `MediaCodec` comes into picture.

I checked this article [Android: MPEG4Writer fails to start when using OMXCodec as MediaSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744905/android-mpeg4writer-fails-to-start-when-using-omxcodec-as-mediasource?rq=1)  but still not able to come to terms with MediaCodec.

1. Is the flow diagram different for Streaming vs Local Playback.
2. How is `MediaCodec` different from `OMXCodec`

I do know that the engine in case of Local Playback is Awesome which is replaced by `NuPlayer` in case of streaming.

Answer (score 3):

From an architectural perspective `OMXCodec` and `ACodec` are the lower most abstractions of an underlying `OMX` component. `OMXCodec` was the first one to be introduced, whereas `ACodec` came into picture with `NuPlayer`.

Both these entities work with an underlying `OMX` component and can support both `audio` and `video` codecs. However, some newer features such as **Adaptive Playback**, `Miracast` are supported through `ACodec` only for the reasons below.

`MediaCodec` is a native (`NDK`) and `Java` (`SDK`) level interface that provides an end-user to instantiate a standalone codec. Android has been exposing the building blocks such as `MediaExtractor`, `MediaMuxer` to provide better flexibility to application developers. `MediaCodec` is one such interface.

Internally `MediaCodec` instantiates an `ACodec` instance and hence, architecturally is a level higher than `OMXCodec`. All new features like `Miracast`, **Adaptive Playback** are reflected in `MediaCodec` only and hence, correspondingly the related changes are seen only in `ACodec`.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for the prompt response. Are there any documents I can get for understanding NuPlayer architecture specially I have heard that from L-OS Google has moved the default engine to NuPlayer.

Comment: @Sam2203 .. The best way to get to know more about `NuPlayer` is to look into the code. I am not sure if there is any published documentation, but there could be some useful information in forums like __SO__. In `Lollipop`, you are right that default player is `NuPlayer`, but `StagefrightPlayer` can also be enabled through system properties. Please have a look here http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerFactory.cpp#63

Comment: @Sam2203.. If you are not satisfied with available literature, please do raise another question. Surely, some of us would be able to help out